# How to insert multiple dynamic data using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter,  I am displaying the fields dynamically. Now I have to insert the data in the database. So I tried below code.

```
$order = $this->input->post('order[]');
$partner = $this->input->post('parner[]');
$bankname = $this->input->post('newpartner[]');
$status = $this->input->post('filestatus[]');
$user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');

$order_length = sizeof($order);

for ($j = 0; $j < $order_length; $j++) {

  if (($status = 1) || ($status = 3)) {
    $remark = $this->input->post('remark[]');
  } else {
    $remark = "";
  }

  if (($status = 2) || ($status = 4))) {
  $reasonDate = $this->input-> post('reasonDate[]');
  $remark = $this->input-> post('remark[]');
} else {
  $reasonDate = "";
  $remark = "";

}

if ($status = 7) {
  $reasonAmt = $this->input->post('reasonAmt[]');
  $reason = $this->input->post('reason[]');
} else {
  $reasonAmt = "";
  $reason = "";
}


$data['row'] = array(
  'order' => $order[$j],
  'bankname' => $bankname[$j],
  'status' => $status[$j],
  'lead_id' => $user_id,
  'remark' => $remark[$j],
  'reasonDate' => $reasonDate[$j],
  'reasonAmt' => $reasonAmt[$j],
  'reason' => $reason[$j]
);
$save = array(
  'b_orderno' => $data['row']['order'],
  'b_bankname' => $data['row']['bankname'],
  'b_filestatus' => $data['row']['status'],
  'p_id' => $data['row']['pid'],
  'lead_id' => $data['row']['lead_id'],
  'b_remark' => $data['row']['remark'],
  'b_date' => $data['row']['reasonDate'],
  'b_amt' => $data['row']['reasonAmt'],
  'b_reason' => $data['row']['reason']
);

$afterxss = $this->security-> xss_clean($save);
if ($afterxss) {
  $this - > db - > insert('tbl_bankdata', $afterxss);
  $response['error'] = "true";
  $response['msg'] = "added successfully";

} else {
  $response['error'] = "false";
  $response['msg'] = "Sometning wrong! please check the internet connection and try again";
}

}
echo json_encode($response);
```

I am getting the issue on the status field because depending upon the status value input field will display.  Also, I used If the condition in logic for the status field.  Each row has a unique status field.

You will find my HTML and script in below link.

https://jsfiddle.net/08phzue3/

This is my UI screenshot. Ignore the value that is only for testing purpose.

1)Onload this will display [image]
2) If user select the status
[image]
3) If multiple row
[image]

Would you help me out with this?

Comment: answer updatedd ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are not comparing here:

```
if (($status = 1) || ($status = 3)) {
```

You are assigning the values to your `$status` variable

this should be:

```
if (($status == 1) || ($status == 3)) {
```

**Side note:** same for other conditions as well.

**Edit:**

As you mentioned you are getting array in `$status` so using comparison is not a correct logic here, there are multiple solution available,

You can use [`in_array()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like:

```
if(in_array(1, $status) || in_array(3, $status)){
    $remark = $this->input->post('remark[]');   
}
else{
    $remark = "";   
}
```

**Final Solutions (04-07-2019):**

After changing the `$save` and `$data` arrays, issue has been resolved for OP:

```
$save['b_orderno'] = $order[$j]; 
$save['b_bankname'] = $bankname[$j]; 
$save['b_filestatus'] = $status[$j]; 
$save['p_id'] = $partner[$j]; 
$save['lead_id'] = $user_id; 


if(!empty($remark[$j])){ 
$save['b_remark'] = $remark[$j]; 
} 
if(!empty($reasonDate[$j])){ 
$save['b_date'] = $reasonDate[$j]; 
} 
if(!empty($message[$j])){ 
$save['b_message'] = $message[$j]; 
} 
if(!empty($reasonAmt[$j])){ 
$save['b_amt'] = $reasonAmt[$j]; 
} 
if(!empty($reason[$j])){ 
$save['b_reason'] = $reason[$j]; 
}


$data['row']['order'] = $order[$j]; 
$data['row']['bankname'] = $bankname[$j]; 
$data['row']['status'] = $status[$j]; 
$data['row']['lead_id'] = $user_id; 
$data['row']['remark'] = $remark[$j]; 
$data['row']['reasonDate'] = $reasonDate[$j]; 

if(!empty($reasonAmt[$j])){ 
$data['row']['reasonAmt'] = $reasonAmt[$j]; 
} 
if(!empty($reason[$j])){ 
$data['row']['reason'] = $reason[$j]; 
}
```

Comment: Oh! Give me some time to check. Can you check my logic, Is it correct? Till the time I am updating your answer with mine.

Comment: @questionbank: i dont think so its correct logic bcoz you are using `filestatus[]` as an array and checking like a string..

Comment: @questionbank: `$this->input->post('filestatus[]')` this will return one value or multiple?

Comment: This is the output of $this->input->post('filestatus[]') Array ( 
[0] => 1 
[1] => 3 
[2] => 2
[3] => 3
)

Comment: You can check here also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839049/how-to-check-the-array-value-in-if-condition/56840465

Comment: @questionbank: there are so many solution, one solution is in_array() check answer, updated

Comment: Let me try with in_array, Should I add status inside for condition?

Comment: @questionbank: yes replace with your current check.. same for all check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195862/discussion-between-questionbank-and-devpro).

Comment: I tried your code but It's working for the only first row, If I click add bank and select all the field and then submit then I am getting the offset error.

Comment: @questionbank: no idea, but i think u need to creare another question and close this one

Comment: but I haven't found the solution.

Comment: @questionbank: i told u in chat , after changing check `echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Yes, I checked and I filled only remark and date and message. The issue is  [reasonAmt] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [reason] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        ) 

both are empty so it should be submitted empty in the database but it's not submitting and getting offset error.